# Update a table then return updated rows in mySQL

Tags: mysql, select

I have the following query:

```
SELECT script FROM d_stages WHERE id IN
(SELECT g.stage + :i FROM games g INNER JOIN sessions s ON
g.expired = 0 AND s.user = g.user AND s.token = :token)
```

1. Inner SELECT looks for a user id in 'sessions' table by a given token, then for a non-expired game for that user.
2. It returns the game stage, which is modified (incremented, decremented, or left with no modification, depending on :i value).
3. Outer SELECT returns a unique script for the found stage from dictionary.

Obviously, the modified stage number (g.stage + :i) should be written back to the DB, since the game has evolved. I can replace `SELECT script` with `SELECT script, g.stage + :i`, and use the modified number in another (`UPDATE`) query, but maybe I can do the same within a single query?

My DBMS is mySQL 5.5.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, there is only one way:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `goto_stage`(IN `inc` INT, IN `session_token` VARCHAR(64))
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    MODIFIES SQL DATA
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN
    DECLARE new_stage INT;
    SELECT g.stage + inc INTO new_stage FROM games g INNER JOIN sessions s ON
            g.expired = 0 AND s.user = g.user AND s.token = session_token;
    UPDATE games SET stage = new_stage;
    SELECT script FROM d_stages WHERE id = new_stage;
END
```

Answer (score 1):

You can update only with an UPDATE query. An UPDATE query can return only one thing: then number of affected rows. So, you cannot update and select the value you need in a single query.

Thus you have to use an extra UPDATE query to update data. You can do it before of after your SELECT query depending of the simplicity or the real point in you code where the new value is supposed to be committed.

Answer (score 0):

No single query solution to mysql. But if your db uses innodb as engine, you can try

```
select ... for update
```

to lock the rows and then do update to it. Check mysql manual "14.3.9.3. SELECT ... FOR UPDATE and SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE Locking Reads" for detail.