# select with update in one query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have a query like:

```
SELECT id, name, surname, fromId, toId, msg_text, readed FROM messages WHERE toId = 2;
```

So I want to `update all selected rows.readed = 1`. And Query must return all selected rows.

These action must do in one query if possibe.

Sorry for my english

Comment: So, if the query affected half a million rows, then you'd want half a million rows returned?

Comment: there is not half a million rows, if there is half a million rows, so, yes i want half a million rows returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No, it is not possible in a single query.

A little less short answer: There is something known as a command-query separation which in short suggests that a command should do something and return nothing and a query should do nothing and return something. I recommend following this principle if you intend on building good software.

I wont get into why this is not possible because I myself am not that much of an SQL guru and I could only guess but I would suggest an easy solution to your problem.

When you get your results then you are most likely processing them in PHP. Assuming the results are sorted in ascending order - on the first iteration grab the minimum id and on the last one grab the maximum id, then run an update query:

```
UPDATE messages SET readed = 1 WHERE toId = ? AND (id >= <minimum id> AND id <= <maximum id>)
```

On a side note - name and surname are probably not what you want to store in a messages table.

Comment: The logic is flawed.

Comment: You could change it to `WHERE id IN(...)`

Comment: @Strawberry but then you would need to get all ids, I suggested only getting the min and max ids because it simpler and also hypothetically if there are a million rows selected I don't think that will work very well with an `IN` clause :/

Comment: If the relevant ids are 1, 5, 7, and 9, your query updates 1 through 9, which is not what's wanted.

Comment: @Strawberry yeah I know but I don't see why the op would want to select inconsequential messages, anyway that was not directly related to the question I just suggested it as a possible solution. Thanks for pointing it out though, I modified the query a little.

Comment: Unless the messages are only ever sent to one toid, then the situation as you see it is highly improbable!

Answer (score 1):

You can update only with an UPDATE query. An UPDATE query can return only one thing: that is number of affected rows. So, you cannot update and select the value you need in a single query.

Have a look here [Update a table then return updated rows in mySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11918251/update-a-table-then-return-updated-rows-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with stored procedure.
Create a stored procedure which executes the update and the select as well.
Eg:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS myproc;
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE myproc()
begin
 set @qry='select id, name, surname, fromId, toId, msg_text, readed from messages where toId = 2';
 prepare query from @qry;
 execute query;
 update messages set readed=1 where toId = 2;
end //
```

Then you can run the query through this procedure.
Eg:

```
$sql = "call myproc()";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["name"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```